# Send data to server machine

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to process some mails, then get the data and send it to server to process the data on DB, the point is that it can be done with google drive but its the tools from the company i works are so capped, i cant download directly from drive and i cant find anything to send the data directly to the server to process it.

I have processed the mails and i get an txt on Google Drive, maybe some way to send it to a domain or something like that...

There is some way to send it without use the tools from Google? Just Google Apps Script.

Comment: See [this tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/urlfetch/info) for more details.

Comment: The question needs more details (maybe also more focus). Are you the server admin? What services has enabled your server? Which of them you would like to use? Have you already look at the Google Apps Script guides and reference docs?